# How to find a mails $mailkey

Tags: 6, emails

I'm trying to theme a couple of different mails generated by notifications using the mimemail module. Is there a reliable method to find a mails mailkey for use in a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to check the mailkey is if you look at the source code of the mail you received. The body-tag has a class with the mailkey. At least if you use the default template.

Comment: Thanks, I'm outputting the mailkey in the actual mail for the time being but oddly it's showing the same key for multiple different emails. Will investigate further.